# for with multiple arrays

Tags: perl, raku

In Scheme you can iterate over multiple lists in with `for-each`:

```
> (for-each (lambda (a b) (display (+ a b)) (newline)) '(10 20 30) '(1 2 3))
11
22
33
>
```

I know that in Perl you can use `for` to iterate over a single list. What's a good way to iterate over multiple lists as in the Scheme example?

I'm interested in answers for Perl 5 or 6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Perl 5 you can use the module [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/dist/List-MoreUtils/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm).  Either with pairwise or with the iterator returned by each_array (which can take more than two arrays to iterate through in parallel).

```
use 5.12.0;
use List::MoreUtils qw(pairwise each_array);

my @one = qw(a b c d e);
my @two = qw(q w e r t);

my @three = pairwise {"$a:$b"} @one, @two;

say join(" ", @three);

my $it = each_array(@one, @two);
while (my @elems = $it->()) {
    say "$elems[0] and $elems[1]";
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In Perl 6, the Zip operator is the nicest choice. If you want to get both values (and not compute the sum directly), you can use it without the plus sign:

```
for (10, 11, 12) Z (1, 2, 3) -> $a, $b {
    say "$a and $b";
}
```

Comment: Thanks mortiz! See my comment to tadzik's answer.

Answer (score 6):

With the Zip operator you can achieve what you're doing with Scheme:

```
> .say for (10, 20, 30) Z+ (1, 2, 3)
11
22
33
```

See http://perlcabal.org/syn/S03.html#Zip_operators

Comment: Thanks tadzik. Scheme's for-each generalizes to 1 or more lists. Can zip be used for more than two lists?

Comment: It can, though Rakudo currently only implements it for two lists (known limitation).

Answer (score 2):

You could just iterate over the indices of the arrays, if you're sure they're the same size:

```
foreach( 0 .. $#array1 ) {
  print $array1[$_] + $array2[$_], "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Algorithm::Loops](http://p3rl.org/Algorithm%3a%3aLoops) offers a MapCar function for iterating over multiple arrays (with variants that deal differently with unequally sized arrays).

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```
sub for_each
{
    my $proc = shift ;

    my $len = @{$_[0]} ;

    for ( my $i = 0 ; $i < $len ; $i++ )
    {
        my @args = map $_->[$i] , @_ ;

        &$proc ( @args ) ;
    }
}

for_each sub { say $_[0] + $_[1] } , ([10,20,30],[1,2,3])
```

Using `each_arrayref` from `List::MoreUtils`:

```
sub for_each
{
    my $proc = shift ;

    my $it = each_arrayref ( @_ ) ;

    while ( my @elts = $it->() ) { &$proc ( @elts ) } ;
}

for_each sub { say $_[0] + $_[1] } , ([10,20,30],[1,2,3])
```

Thanks to Alex for pointing out `List::MoreUtils`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the question is as simple as just adding (/multiplying, dividing,…) and the 
Arrays are no Arrays of Arrays, you also could use the hyper-operators for your task:

```
<1 2 3> «+» <10 20 30>
```

(of course this is a Perl6 answer)

if you don't have access to the French quotes `«»`, you could rewrite it as

```
<1 2 3> <<+>> <10 20 30>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution (there are many to choose from) might look like this:

```
my @argle = (10, 20, 30);
my @bargle = (1, 2, 3);
do {
    my $yin = shift @argle;
    my $yang = shift @bargle;
    say $yin + $yang;
} while (@argle && @bargle);
```

I sense that you are asking about `foreach`, which might look like this:

```
my @argle = (10, 20, 30);
my @bargle = (1, 2, 3);
for my $yin (@argle) {
    my $yang = shift @bargle;
    say $yin + $yang;
}
```

But it is not as smooth in this case. What happens if either array is shorter?